# Regular Expressions and check on form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, expression

I have a code here and now I want to add regular expressions to it.
On the "Bedrijfsnaam" it needs to be accepted to use alphabetic characters, numbers, spaces and a few symbols like: . - _ and @.
On the "Contactpersoon" it only needs to be accepted to use alphabetic characters, spaces and dots.
For the "Email" it needs to be accepted to use alphabetic characters and a ., followed by a @, then alphabetic characters and a -, a . and after that a maximum of 3 alphabetic characters //This is because i also want this email adresses to be able: r.kameel@noordkabels.nl or r.kameel@noord-kabels.nl

on "Telefoonnummer" it only needs to be accepted to use 10 digits.

This is the javascript code I allready have:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["Bedrijfsnaam"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("De bedrijfsnaam is niet ingevuld, u wordt verzocht dit veld in te vullen.");
  return false;
  }

  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["Contactpersoon"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("De naam van de contactpersoon is niet ingevuld, u wordt verzocht dit veld in te vullen.");
  return false;
  }


  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Het E-mailadres van de contactpersoon is niet ingevuld, u wordt verzocht dit veld in te vullen.");
  return false;
  }

    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["Telefoonnummer"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Het telefoonnummer van de contactpersoon is niet ingevuld, u wordt verzocht dit veld in te vullen.");
  return false;
  }


      var x=document.forms["myForm"]["option1"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Zoekwoordcombinatie 1 van de gewenste zoekwoordcombinaties waarop uw bedrijf online vindbaar wil zijn is niet ingevuld, u wordt verzocht dit veld in te vullen.");
  return false;
  }


}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a useful library for regular expressions at the following website:
 http://regexlib.com/

Answer (score 0):

RegExpes are absolutely the way to go. You should do some more research on them though, people are busy with their own work you know :-)

Learning RegExes are a lot easier with an interactive interpreter. There are tons on the internet, here is one random one : http://regexpal.com/